# Zend Framework2 form error messages

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

Here is my code below, to create a login form

```
    class LoginForm extends Form
    {
            public function __construct($name = null)
            {
                parent::__construct('login');
                $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
                $this->add(array('name'=>'uname','attributes'=>array('type'=>'text',),
                    'options'=>array('label'=>'UserName'),
                ));

                $this->add(array('name'=>'pword','attributes'=>array('type'=>'password',),
                    'options'=>array('label'=>'Password'),
                ));

                $this->add(array('name'=>'submit','attribute'=>array('type'=>'submit',
                    'value' => 'Go',
                'class'=>'submit','id'=>'submitbutton',)  
                ));
            }
    }
```

Below is the code for my login page

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('users', array('action' => 'login')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('uname'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('pword'));
echo $this->formElementerrors($form->get('pword'));

echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));

echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Form works fine with no issues but :

1. It is not taking the value for `submit` if I see viewsource it shows `value=''`
2. I want to display error message where ever I wish how to achive that?
   I tried this 
   `echo $this->formElementerrors($form->getMessages('uname'));` but did not work any suggestion or ideas to fix this?

Below is my controller code...

```
$form = new LoginForm();
$request = $this->getRequest();

if ($request->isPost()) {
    $post = $request->getPost();
    if($post->get('uname')=='')
    {
        $umessage='please enter username';
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('users',array('action'=>'login'));
    }

    $this->db =$this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');
    $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($this->db);
    $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
        ->setIdentityColumn('uname')
        ->setCredentialColumn('pword');

    $authAdapter->setIdentity($post->get('uname'))
        ->setCredential(md5($post->get('pword')));

    $authService = new AuthenticationService();
    $authService->setAdapter($authAdapter);

    $result = $authService->authenticate();

    if ($result->isValid()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('users');
    } else {
        switch ($result->getCode()) {
            case Result::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND:
                echo 'user name not valid dude';
                break;

            case Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID:
                echo 'password incorrect';
                break;

            case Result::SUCCESS:
                echo 'login successfull';
                break;
        }

    }
}
$this->layout('layout/index');
return array('form' => $form);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You syntax is incorrect for displaying individual error messages, try this:

change:

```
$this->formElementerrors($form->getMessages('uname')); // incorrect
$this->formElementErrors($form->get('uname')); // correct
```

example:

```
<?php foreach($form->getElements() as $element): ?>
    <?php if($element->getLabel()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->formLabel($element) ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($element, array('class' => 'inline')); ?>
   <?php echo $this->formElement($element) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Notice I am passing in the actual element, not via getMessages().

you also have a type on your button definition (missing `s` on the end):

```
attribute => attributes
```

see below:

```
$this->add(array(
     'name'=>'submit',
     'attributes' => array(
         'type'=>'submit',
         'value' => 'Go',
         'class'=>'submit','id'=>'submitbutton',
      )  
));
```

I am assuming you have also setup your input filters too?

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name'     => 'username',
    'required' => true,
    'filters'  => array(
        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'name'    => 'StringLength',
            'options' => array(
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'min'      => 1,
                'max'      => 100,
            ),
        ),
    ),
)));
```

Comment: Hello @Andrew my second problem is resolved , but 1st problem still the same,,...i have already tried `$this->formElementerrors($form->get('uname'));` it does not display error message.. :( i have even tried concating with some varible, variable will be displayed but not the error message

Comment: Have you tried using the correct camelCase, formElementerrors => formElementErrors not sure if ZF2 uses the capitals to resolve on view helpers, it may be the case. I guess there's another issue as formRow should also show errors if there are any. Have you got validation/filters setup correctly? can you post?

Comment: i think i have not setup input filter.. let me check and update...but iam using authentication plugin it should handle it by itself right?please do check by updated question

Comment: I think the actual form requires the input filter to do it's validation and to generate any messages from the failure of that. The code you pasted is checking the credentials but doesn't validate the form elements

Comment: yes now even i think the same, well let me try to pass it through variable ... and display the error message.....,,,thanks alot @Andrew you always solve my zend issues...i will be waiting for you to be online bcos you are the only guy who responds to my zend questions :) iam very thankfull to you....god bless you....